# Sending Data to JS Form from iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, forms, jsp

The Red Cross has a [locator page](http://www.redcross.org/where) where you can submit a zip code by means of a form and that runs through a JSP to return contact information for your local Red Cross office.

From an iOS app, I have the user's zip code and would like to run this process and get that contact information back... or at least the appropriate URL to link to.  I was hoping I could find some way to pass the zip code by URL but it doesn't look like it's going to be that easy.

Could anyone offer some direction as to how to go about this?  I've done some simple things with forms before but I'm not quite sure where to start with this one.

Comment: quick question: what have you tried so far? Did you take a look at AFNetworking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `<form>` action parameter, that's the URL you have to `post` your data to:
`http://www.redcross.org//portal/site/en/template.MAXIMIZE/ziplocator/;jsessionid=MWwKPvjSWmvz8p4XrRtNLVL0VCTM7fcwfnFnKHpwRhJTnwLMMDcv!-1938881463!-1334769155?javax.portlet.tpst=2bd907ea326f7e9e934afa36c23f78a0_ws_MX&javax.portlet.prp_2bd907ea326f7e9e934afa36c23f78a0_viewID=result&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&vgnextoid=6d65e821cbdf9110VgnVCM1000002bf3870aRCRD`

The field name is `zipcode`. The AFNetworking documentation is quite okay explaining how to send a POST request. I would also recommend the nsscreencasts series, he has an episode on AFNetworking as well.

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSURLConnection to execute a post request and return the result, you may have to do some parsing of the result though depending on the format it is returned in.

Here is an example:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=689884

NSURLConnection documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html